# Getting jersey exception on wildfly9

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, jersey, wildfly-9

My application was initially working fine on `Jboss5` and now I deployed it on `Wildfly9`. And I am getting below **exception:**

```
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.sun.jersey.core.header.MediaTypes
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.sun.jersey.core.header.MediaTypes
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.factory.MessageBodyFactory.initReaders(MessageBodyFactory.java:182)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.factory.MessageBodyFactory.initReaders(MessageBodyFactory.java:176)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.factory.MessageBodyFactory.init(MessageBodyFactory.java:162)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.init(Client.java:343)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.access$000(Client.java:119)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client$1.f(Client.java:192)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client$1.f(Client.java:188)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:193)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.<init>(Client.java:188)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.<init>(Client.java:160)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.create(Client.java:673)
```

Following `jersey` jars are already present in the lib but still I am getting this error. can anyone please help me with any pointer.

```
jersey-client-1.19.3.jar
jersey-core-1.19.3.jar
```

Comment: Any particular reason why you're manually providing a different JAX-RS implementation along with the webapp while WildFly already provides its own (known as RESTEasy)?

Comment: this application is using an external jar and that jar is using following: import com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse.Status;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.UniformInterfaceException;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource;

Comment: I know. I'm just asking you why exactly you're doing that. All this mess with extra JARs is namely unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

As point by @BalusC, you don't need to add jersey bundle as `wildfly9` comes along with `RestEASY`, which is similar to `Jersey` an implementation of `JAX-RS`. So, you are mixing `jersey` and `resteasy` in same application.

If you look at the exception, it is trying to load class from jersey

```
Could not initialize class com.sun.jersey.core.header.MediaTypes
```

So, you need to change the implementation to load from RestEASY (if you have something similar there)